# How to display certain lines from the Get-EventLog cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How to display certain lines from a message?

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Error -Newest 10 -Message "*3CXPhone.exe*" |
     Format-Table -wrap
```

Specifically in my example, I want to display only 1,2 and 7,8 rows. How to do it?

[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyRT3.png) my example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
$lines = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Error -Newest 10 -Message "*.exe*"    
for($i=1;$i -lt 10;$i++){
    switch ($i) 
    { 
        1 {$lines[$i]} 
        2 {$lines[$i]} 
        7 {$lines[$i]} 
        8 {$lines[$i]}         
    }
}
```

So basically you create an array $lines. And use a counter $i , to match the counter to the index of the array.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need all the events, but I want to output only the specified lines from the message, as I have shown in the screenshot. This can be done?

Comment: Sorry i missed the image. yes this can be done, i've posted an other answer. You should get a look at "get-member".

Answer (score 0):

```
    Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Error -Newest 10 -Message "*.exe*"    | where {$_.Message -like '*.exe*'} |  Format-Table -wrap
```